# Как найти все URL внутри HTML с помощью Python?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Я знаю о существовании **BeautifulSoup** и его возможностях по разбору (и замене) HTML. Но в реальности задача оказывается ему не по зубам.

Для начала URL может встречаться не только в `<a href="URL">что-то</a>` или `<img src="URL" />` , но и в `<link href="URL" />`, в `<script src="URL"></script>`, в `<iframe src="URL"` ... а еще в стилях (например, как `background-image:url(URL)` или `@import url(URL)` ...), а ещё во встроенных SVG (например, как `<a xlink:href="URL"`)... и так далее.

Кроме того, URL может встречаться в конструкциях типа
`<object data="URL" type="image/svg+xml" ...></object>` или даже внутри встроенных JavaScript... а еще бывает что **BeautifulSoup** обраруживает, что-то что похоже на URL, но им не является (например, `<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64`).

Все эти варианты найти с помощью **BeautifulSoup** не просто, но еще можно. Но он поможет, если некоторые HTM-теги не закрыты. Например, попадется конструкция `<link href="URL">` (без финализирующей `/>`) и тогда **BeautifulSoup** "проглотит" весь дальнейший HTML до следующего  (а его может не и быть).

Если же использовать регулярные выражения, то все становится очень сложно, т.к. URL внутри HTML может быть не оформлен в кавычки (и тогда он воспринимается до ближайшего пробела). Или иметь произвольные пробельные символы (например:

```html
<a href
=
"URL"> ...
```

Я думаю случаев употребления URL намного больше. И как их все разобрать? Написать универсальное регулярное выражение для всех случаев -- не способен, а **BeautifulSoup**, как я объяснил, не всегда помогает. Есть ли какие-нибудь альтернативы по обнаружению URL?

Comment: Преобразуйте ответ в текст и парсите текст. В чем проблема?

Comment: Понятно, что иначе никак. Но есть куча инструментов парсинга и хочется выбрать лучший... С учётом того, что иногда придется парсить невалидный HTML